# Java Vlcj - How to change media in EmbbededMediaPlayerComponent

Tags: java, javafx, vlcj

So I have a EmbbededMediaPlayerComponent and Javafx list full of urls which can be played in EmbbededMediaPlayerComponent. The one on which you click is then supposed to be played in EmbbededMediaPlayerComponent. The first url you choose works just fine and is displayed in the player. The thing is, after I choose another url I want the first one to be replaced with the second one. What is the correct way to dispose the first media and then play the second one?

Comment: If your satisfied with a answer then don't forget to accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the "correct" way to do it but I would do:

```
EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPLayer().playMedia(mrlToMedia);
```

If I have understood correctly this should just load the next file and start playing that one.

It's also possible to use

```
EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPLayer().startMedia(String mrl);
```

which should try to start the playback with the difference that this is a blocking operation untill playback has started.

Also possible to do

```
EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPLayer().prepareMedia(String mrl);
EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPLayer().start();
```

This is the same as the one above but in two steps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i would like to know one more thing. What is the correct way to release the first media before it has ended and play the second one?

Comment: I am not able to double check this but why not just EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPLayer(). stop() and then do EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPLayer().playMedia(mrl);?

Comment: Well it seems like vlcj have some problem with memory access when I try to change the media.

Comment: Weird.. Though without any error code we probably won't be able to help with that! Caprica might but he's awesome.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is this:

```
mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia(mrl);
```

Which should be exactly the same as how you played your initial media.