# how to change media in mediaplayer not mediaplayercomponent in vlcj?

Tags: swing, javafx, vlcj

I'm making desktop application using **swing** and **vlcj**. I had divided frame into two part one side webbrowser which is having url of several videos and in another panel vlcj to play that url in mediaplayer. The first url you choose works just fine and is displayed in the player. The thing is, after I choose another url I want the first one to be replaced with the second one. What is the correct way to dispose the first media and then play the second one? The second problem is I had set the vlcj in panel but its openning video in vlc direct 3d output can you tell me why it is not openning in panel canvas. 
This is the code what I tried:

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlcConst;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.discovery.NativeDiscovery;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerEventAdapter;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerFactory;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.EmbeddedMediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;
/**
 *
 * @author biznis
 */
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
JScrollPane scrollableTextArea;
    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
            //JFrame jFrame2 = new JFrame("vlcj Tutorial");
        MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
        canvas1.setBackground(Color.black);
       jPanel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
     jPanel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,300));
         jPanel2.add(canvas1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // frame.add(jPanel2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      //  frame.add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
         EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(canvas1));

         //jPanel2.setLayout(new java.awt.CardLayout());
          //jFrame2.setVisible(true);
        //jFrame2.setLocation(100, 100);

       JPanel p1 = new JPanel();

        p1.setBounds(100, 900, 105, 200);
      jPanel2.add(p1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
         JButton playbutton = new JButton();

        playbutton.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/biznis/Desktop/Newspaper/sangbadpratidin/d/play.png"));
        //  this.setSize(800,450);
        playbutton.setBounds(50, 50, 150, 100);
        playbutton.setToolTipText("Play");
        p1.add(playbutton);

        JButton pausebutton = new JButton();

        pausebutton.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/biznis/Desktop/Newspaper/sangbadpratidin/d/pause.png"));
        pausebutton.setToolTipText("pause");
        pausebutton.setBounds(80, 50, 150, 100);

        p1.add(pausebutton);
        JButton previousbutton = new JButton();
        previousbutton.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/biznis/Desktop/Newspaper/sangbadpratidin/d/previous.png"));
        previousbutton.setBounds(90, 50, 150, 100);
        previousbutton.setToolTipText("Skip back");
        p1.add(previousbutton);
        JButton nextbutton = new JButton();
        nextbutton.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/biznis/Desktop/Newspaper/sangbadpratidin/d/next.png"));
        nextbutton.setBounds(90, 50, 150, 100);
        nextbutton.setToolTipText(" Skip forward");
        p1.add(nextbutton);
        JButton captureButton = new JButton();

        captureButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/biznis/Desktop/Newspaper/sangbadpratidin/d/icons8-unsplash-26.png"));
        captureButton.setToolTipText("capture");
        captureButton.setBounds(80, 50, 150, 100);

        p1.add(captureButton);
        JSlider volumeSlider = new JSlider();
        volumeSlider.setMinimum(LibVlcConst.MIN_VOLUME);
        volumeSlider.setMaximum(LibVlcConst.MAX_VOLUME);
        volumeSlider.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 40));
        volumeSlider.setToolTipText("Change volume");
        p1.add(volumeSlider);
        JSlider js = new JSlider();
      p1.add(js);
         // mediaPlayer.playMedia("D:\\test\\192.168.2.201_01_20180124_153000.avi");
         js.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                if (js.getValue() / 100 < 1) {
                    mediaPlayer.setPosition((float) js.getValue() / 100);
                }
            }
        });

        Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                js.setValue(Math.round(mediaPlayer.getPosition() * 100));
            }

        });

        timer.start();
        pausebutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                // or mediaPlayer.pause() depending on what works.
                final long time = mediaPlayer.getTime();
                System.out.println(time);

            }
        });
        playbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                mediaPlayer.play();
            }
        });
        previousbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                mediaPlayer.skip(-10000);
            }
        });
        nextbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                mediaPlayer.skip(1000);
            }
        });
        volumeSlider.addChangeListener(new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                mediaPlayer.setVolume(volumeSlider.getValue());
            }
        });
        captureButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                File file3 = new File("C:/Test/");
                mediaPlayer.saveSnapshot(file3);
                try {
                    BufferedImage image3 = ImageIO.read(file3);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });





         JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
jPanel1.add(jfxPanel);

// Creation of scene and future interactions with JFXPanel
// should take place on the JavaFX Application Thread
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    WebView webView = new WebView();
   WebEngine wb1 = webView.getEngine();
    jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(webView));
    wb1.load("");
    wb1.getLoadWorker().stateProperty()
                .addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {
                        if (newState == Worker.State.SCHEDULED) {
                          frame.setTitle(wb1.getLocation());
                            String trgurl = wb1.getLocation();
                            System.out.println(trgurl);
                              if (trgurl.matches("(.*)video=(.*)")) {


                                  int n = trgurl.indexOf("video=");
                                  //String str1 = Integer.toString(n);
                                  System.out.println(n + 6);
                                  int len = trgurl.length();
                                  System.out.println("string length is: " + trgurl.length());
                                  System.out.println(trgurl.substring(n+6,len));
                                  String find =  "file:" +trgurl.substring(n+6,len);
                                  System.out.println(find);
                                 //   mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(canvas1));

                              mediaPlayer.prepareMedia(find);
                              mediaPlayer.start();

                        JScrollPane scrollableTextArea = new JScrollPane(jPanel2);  

        scrollableTextArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);  
        scrollableTextArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);  




        }
    }
                }
});
        });
    } 

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
         jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 300));
        canvas1 = new java.awt.Canvas();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 300));
        getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout());
        getContentPane().add(jPanel2);

        jPanel1.add(canvas1);

        getContentPane().add(jPanel1);
      // getContentPane().add(sp);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        new NativeDiscovery().discover();
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                 frame = new NewJFrame();

                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }
private static NewJFrame frame;
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private java.awt.Canvas canvas1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
  }
```

in jpanel1 im openning vlcj and jpanel2 webview. Please help. Thanks in advance.

This is exception log when i click on next link of video:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The video surface component must be displayable
    at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.videosurface.CanvasVideoSurface.attach(CanvasVideoSurface.java:75)
    at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.DefaultEmbeddedMediaPlayer.attachVideoSurface(DefaultEmbeddedMediaPlayer.java:156)
    at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.DefaultEmbeddedMediaPlayer.onBeforePlay(DefaultEmbeddedMediaPlayer.java:315)
    at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.DefaultMediaPlayer.play(DefaultMediaPlayer.java:705)
    at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.DefaultMediaPlayer.playMedia(DefaultMediaPlayer.java:222)
    at javaapplication6.NewJFrame$9.changed(NewJFrame.java:231)
    at javaapplication6.NewJFrame$9.changed(NewJFrame.java:211)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.java:74)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:102)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.updateState(WebEngine.java:1287)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.dispatchLoadEvent(WebEngine.java:1388)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.access$1200(WebEngine.java:1280)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$PageLoadListener.dispatchLoadEvent(WebEngine.java:1267)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.fireLoadEvent(WebPage.java:2499)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.fwkFireLoadEvent(WebPage.java:2343)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.twkProcessMouseEvent(Native Method)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.dispatchMouseEvent(WebPage.java:807)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebView.processMouseEvent(WebView.java:1045)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebView.lambda$registerEventHandlers$32(WebView.java:1168)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.EmbeddedScene.lambda$null$293(EmbeddedScene.java:256)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.EmbeddedScene.lambda$mouseEvent$294(EmbeddedScene.java:244)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Vlcj - How to change media in EmbbededMediaPlayerComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48312182/java-vlcj-how-to-change-media-in-embbededmediaplayercomponent)

Comment: there its using embbededMediaPlayerComponent but im using embbededMediaPlayer and the solution present in the link i had tried already but it doesnot work im getting same exception.

Comment: and my output video is openning in another window not panel that is also the problem.

Comment: i had edit my code also accto link still same error

Comment: well i thought on the face of it it might be a duplicate because there is no difference in how you change media in media player vs embedded media player component - it is the same

Comment: its problem with component i had changed

Answer (score 0):

Thnx i had solved the problem by taking left and right panel with scroll pane.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javax.swing.*;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.discovery.NativeDiscovery;



public class MyTestClass extends JFrame {
EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent playerCmpt;
    public MyTestClass() {
        new NativeDiscovery().discover();

        EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent playerCmpt = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
       playerCmpt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));

        JPanel leftPane = new JPanel();
        leftPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
leftPane.add(jfxPanel);
//jPanel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
//jPanel1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
// Creation of scene and future interactions with JFXPanel
// should take place on the JavaFX Application Thread
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    WebView webView = new WebView();
   WebEngine wb1 = webView.getEngine();
    jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(webView));
    wb1.load("");
    wb1.getLoadWorker().stateProperty()
                .addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {
                        if (newState == Worker.State.SCHEDULED) {
                      //    this.setTitle(wb1.getLocation());
                            String trgurl = wb1.getLocation();
                            System.out.println(trgurl);
                              if (trgurl.matches("(.*)video=(.*)")) {


                                  int n = trgurl.indexOf("video=");
                                  //String str1 = Integer.toString(n);
                                  System.out.println(n + 6);
                                  int len = trgurl.length();
                                  System.out.println("string length is: " + trgurl.length());
                                  System.out.println(trgurl.substring(n+6,len));
                                  String find =  "file:" +trgurl.substring(n+6,len);
                                  System.out.println(find);
                                  //   mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(canvas1));

                                 // mediaPlayer.release();
                                  playerCmpt.getMediaPlayer().playMedia(find);

                                  // mediaPlayer.stop();
                         // mediaPlayer.prepareMedia(find);

                         // mediaPlayer.stop();
                          //mediaPlayer.prepareMedia(find);
                                  //JScrollPane scrollableTextArea = new JScrollPane(jPanel2);
                                  //scrollableTextArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
                                  //scrollableTextArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);




        }
    }
                }
});
        });


        JPanel playerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        playerPanel.add(playerCmpt);

        JSplitPane mainSplit = new JSplitPane(
            JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,
            leftPane, playerPanel);

        playerPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(10, 10));

        this.add(mainSplit);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //playerCmpt.getMediaPlayer().playMedia("D:\\test\\192.168.2.201_01_20180124_153000.avi");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyTestClass();
    }
}
```